# Why linking and calling a C function with variadic arguments in Rust causes random functions to be called?

Tags: function, rust, variadic-functions, ffi, rust-cargo

I was playing with Rust FFI and I was trying to link `printf` C function, which has variadic arguments, with my Rust executable. After I ran the executable I witnessed some strange behavior.

This is my Rust code:

```rust
use cty::{c_char, c_int};

extern "C" {
    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...) -> c_int;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        printf("One number: %d\n".as_ptr() as *const i8, 69);
        printf("Two numbers: %d %d\n".as_ptr() as *const i8, 11, 12);
        printf(
            "Three numbers: %d %d %d\n".as_ptr() as *const i8,
            30,
            31,
            32,
        );
    }
}
```

This is the output after running `cargo run`:

```
cargo run
   Compiling c-bindings v0.1.0 (/home/costin/Rust/c-bindings)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.20s
     Running `target/debug/c-bindings`
One number: 1
Two numbers: 1 11376
Three numbers: 0 0 0
Two numbers: 11 12
Three numbers: 0 0 56
Three numbers: 30 31 32
```

I looks like the first `printf` calls the second and the third with random parameters, then the second `printf` calls the third one with random parameters because the expected output should have been:

```
One number: 1
Two numbers: 11 12
Three numbers: 30 31 32
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this strange behavior happening?

Comment: Yes, this answers my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust strings are not null-terminated like `printf` expects. You'll need to either manually include `\0` at the end of your format strings or use [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html):

```
printf("One number: %d\n\0".as_ptr() as *const i8, 69);
```

```
use std::ffi::CString;
let s = CString::new("One number: %d\n").unwrap();
printf(s.as_ptr(), 69);
```